# Custom image on uinvigation bar without borders

Tags: objective-c, xcode

[The way the barbutton looks in first view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mx7m5j7f6c4x70i/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-12%20at%204.53.32%20PM.png)

I am trying to create custom barbutton items as shown with out borders. I made it, but in the next view it is having a different rightbarbutton item, and there the previous rightbarbutton item is overlapping. Can anyone please help me.

[the way the barbutton of first view overlapping the barbutton item of next view](https://www.dropbox.com/s/09d56vxqfpdyqwy/Screen%20Shot%202013-02-12%20at%205.00.19%20PM.png)

The code goes like this:

`    UIButton *refreshButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(285, 9, 27, 27)];

```
[refreshButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Refresh_Icon.png"]   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[refreshButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:refreshButton];`
```

Comment: Can you post some code on how you are adding button to the navigation bar.

Comment: how did you produce the output?

Comment: i have added it Mrs Tang

Answer (score 0):

Try setting self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = NO; in VC's viewDidLoad method.

Comment: rightBarButtonItem is NOT BOOL. If he should at all needs to clear it then he must do it like this self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;